# Obtain Kerberos token when using SAML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, kerberos, saml

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that interacts with SCOM. When a user fetches data in our application from SCOM we impersonate that current user so the correct SCOM permissions still apply to them. Currently we use Windows Identity however we would like to add SAML so users can perform SSO and admins can add their own additional security (2FA etc).

My question is when performing a SAML logon, what is the correct way to obtain a kerberos token for the associated user as I require it to communicate with SCOM?

Can we use something like ADFS to send the token as a claim?
[image: Flow diagram where ADFS returns kerberos token]

Or do we need to get the users AD login name and request impersonation from the AD server?
[image: Flow diagram where the application fetches the kerberos token manually]

Comment: I seriously doubt you can get your first diagram working, however you can write your own ADFS extensions, so you can obtain kerberos ticket when the user authenticates in ADFS and package it in the outgoing SAML payload as an additional claim.

Security of this solution would be somewhat questionable when interacting over open web.

Further, if you are considering using ADFS (e.g. your diagram one), how are you using Kerberos to talk to SCOM?

Because if you're deployed in the domain, you just need to run as service account with delegation and you only need username to impersonate

Comment: Thanks @zaitsman that's really helpful. Could you elaborate on your last comment about only needing the username to impersonate? I'm a bit ignorant about SCOM's options of impersonation (but planning to look into). I just know we need to have the users correct permissions when interacting with SCOM. Our application can either run as network service or a custom user.

Comment: It's not so much SCOM doing it, it's basically your app doing it.

So from C# code perspective it is easy as:
`WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null; try { var identity = new WindowsIdentity("username"); var ctx = identity.Impersonate(); } finally { ctx?.undo(); }`

If `identity.Impersonate();` succeeds then any code until the end of the block runs as that user.

Comment: In order for this to succeed, though, you need to configure your principal for SPN delegation, if you're using 'network service' then it's the computer account you're after.
Further, make sure you set IIS to load user profile as otherwise delegation won't work.

Since you didn't include anything about how your app is interacting with SCOM nor any code it's hard to provide more detailed advice

Comment: Our solution to this in the end was to use Web Application Proxy with ADFS. We just couldn't get the impersonation API working and it is depreciated in .NET 5. Web Application Proxy takes on the task of giving the kerberos token to our application. All we need to do is be Windows Authentication mode.